# Why this function is null?

Tags: flutter, function, dart

Im need that function for callback, but it gives a null,

```
int? _handleIncrement(int? variable) {
    if (variable == null) {
      variable = 0;
    } else if (variable < 5) {
      variable++;
    } else {
      variable;
    }
  

  void _incrementVariable(int? variable) {
    
        variable = _handleIncrement(variable);
  }
  
  int? val;
  _incrementVariable(val);
```

I need it in a button

This is the button

```
class ExpTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String name;
  final void Function(int?) onIncrement;

  final List<Widget> children;
  final int? variable;

  ExpTile(
      {required this.name,
      this.children = const <Widget>[],
      required this.onIncrement,
      required this.variable,
      key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: ExpansionTile(
          title: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              onIncrement(variable);
            },
            child: Row(
              children: [Text(name), Text(variable.toString())],
            ),
          ),
          children: children),
    );
  }
```

This is the way I call the widget in the father page

```
ExpTile(
              name: "Defense",
              variable: defense,
              onIncrement: _incrementVariable,
              children: [])
```

I'm trying different things in dartpad, but I don´t know why the logic doesn't work. always return me the initial value of defense.  I'm reading different things about dart functions and callbacks but I dont know where is the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to define `variable` in the parent Widget, if you want to see changes there

```
class ParentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ParentWidget({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<ParentWidget> createState() => _ParentWidgetState();
}

class _ParentWidgetState extends State<ParentWidget> {
  int? variable; //here


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //your widgets...
              ExpTile(
              name: "Defense",
              variable: variable,
              onIncrement: _incrementVariable,
              children: [])
     //the rest of your widgets...
  }
}
```

Then you have to define you increment function as a function which changes your variable's value, and redraw the widget.

```
  void _incrementVariable() {
        setState(() {
          if (variable == null) {
            variable = 0;
          } else if (variable! < 5) {
            variable = variable! + 1;
          } 
        });
  }
```

and then call the function (In the `ExpTile` widget) this way:

```
       onPressed: () {
          widget.onIncrement();
        },
```

Comment: Hi, still not working for me

Comment: I added more info... try with this

Comment: Still the same...

Comment: I see the error... let me update

Comment: Already done, try again

Comment: I have two errors in the setState : "'variable' can't be used as a setter because it's final.\nTry finding a different setter, or making 'variable' non-final." and the second one in widget.onIncrement "This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.\nTry checking to see if you're using the correct API; there might be a function or call that returns void you didn't expect. Also check type parameters and variables which might also be void."

Comment: I quit the final of variable and the void of the function but still do the same. Thanks for your time

Comment: Still not working?

Comment: No, I make the last changes not fianl variable and not void function, The code have no errors but not working.

Comment: And which is the problem? The variable doesn't update? It updates wrong? It updates but doesn't render the new value on the screen?

Comment: The variable doesn't update, it return the starting value, if i declared it null return null, if i declared it int 5 return 5.

Comment: You have put widget.variable = widget.onIncrement(widget.variable);?

Comment: Inside the setState yes, I have restarted vscode, and now do a different thing, if I declare null the variable, It change to 0 before press the button, and if I press it doesnt change. If I declared as an int it doesnt change before or after I press the button

Comment: check that you copied the code correctly, and if you did, run a flutter clean. I have just tried the same code and works

Comment: Still the same, I checked and copy paste your code. Doing tests I see that inside the children widget ExpTile the variable is 0 but in the parent the variable declared as Int? defense;, and passed to the reusable widget as variable = _incrementVariable(defense) is null. They are not even the same. I run flutter clean 3 times, in the second one I had to run "flutter packages get" due to a problem (Target of URI doesn't exist).

Comment: I just create a new project. Only with that widget. The widget in this case work, it start in 0 , I don´t know why it doesn't start in null, but sum 1 each click. The problem is that the variable passed like that:  variable: _incrementVariable(_variable) doesn't change.

Comment: It doesn't change because as I said before, the arguments in Dart are by value, not by reference... Let me change the code

Comment: Ok, but I have 260 variables, with this last method I need a function for each varaible no?

Comment: Yes, but if you want the parent widget to know the variable's value, this is the way to do it. If you have 260 variables, probably you have to review the structure of your project. Provably it will useful a Provider

Comment: Difficult for me, I'm trying to create the method in my provider model but i have problems with too many things, thanks for the help.