# How to create a method inside a provider class

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to be clear and precise. I have a database with 260 variables, I have a data model class and a SQLiteHelper class. I'm using a provider and I have all the CRUD inside.

The problem comes because I have scrolleable page in which I want to be able to change all variables. Around 240 variables are int? and each one will have a button which do the same, convert it to zero if it is null or add 1 if it is an integer. I'm not using a normal callback because in that scrolleable page I use different reusable buttons and I want to know the value of the variable in child and parent widget. In the reusable buttons for change color and text, and in the parent widget(scrolleable page) to save them in SQlite at the end of the page with a save button.

This is my provider class

```
class DBProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  final SQLiteHelper0 _db = SQLiteHelper0();

  List<DB> _items = [];

  Future<void> loadDB() async {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> data = await _db.charDB;
    _items = data.map((DB) {
      return DB(
          id: charDB["id"],
          name: charDB["name"],...// the rest of the CRUD
```

I'm trying something like that

```
dynamic increment(index){
  if(_items[index] != int?){

    return _items[index];

  } else if (_items[index]! == null){
    return _items[index]== 0;
  }else { return _items[index] + 1;}
 }
```

an then in the scrolleable page make another function like that

```
late DBProvider _dBProvier;

void _increment(index){setState(() {
    _dBProvider.increment(index);
  });}
```

I am having different problems, at times I think that nothing makes sense. But if it is a totally dumb way, please give me some direction to keep trying. This question is related with other question where I focused the problem in a different and wrong way [Why this function is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75082909/why-this-function-is-null)
Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean a single table with 260 column names?  If so, do any of the names end with digits like "foo1, foo2, foo3"?  And if so, the first step is to learn database normalization, immediately.

Comment: I was passing the big table to a multitable database, but I have the same problem, how can I make a mehod inside the provider, because now I have a tables, with 20-40 integers, but I dont know how to create the method. The column aren't consecutives, like foo1, foo2...